# Error with firebase Auth when starting ):

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
    objc[4129]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/            Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11d1ec998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x11d00e880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-01-31 20:28:24.620 Reminder[4129:144700] WARNING: Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2017-01-31 20:28:24.917 Reminder[4129:144700] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Reminder.LoginViewController 0x7fbeabd0a6f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Password.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c196d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bbf821e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c196c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010b7069df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010c755293 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010c9c979e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c13b9e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c9c8122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c75b9c5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c75c2e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c75c61c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c75ce70 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c6264b5 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c626c06 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c63a519 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c5b2f8d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c5b90ed -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010c5b626d -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111bbc6cb __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111bbc544 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111bbc8cd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c13b761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c12098c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c11fe76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c11f884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010c5b4aea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010c5bac68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  Reminder                            0x000000010a4a94bf main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e86868d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Get this when starting the app when I goto a view with firebase auth enabled.
The Worst thing is even when I remove the firebase auth and just have blank view it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add the `FIRApp.configure()` into the App delegate